# How to get all the Rules and Filters from GeoServer for specific Workspace

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am using GeoServer 2.4.2 for storing my vector data. And I created a style for a layer
now I want to fetch all the Rules and Filters from style which I created on my work-space.
I am currently using this url for getting output :

```
http://mydomain.com/geoserver/rest/sldservice/{layerName}
```

But I am getting a default screen as shown :

[image]
Can anybody please let me know is there any way to get all Rules and Filters from GeoServer for specific Workspace ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for my question.Here is the link http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html

i get the all the features for particular layer for my worksapce.
  The GetFeature operation returns a selection of features from the data source.

```
This request will execute a GetFeature request for a given layer namespace:featuretype:

http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=2.0.0&
  request=GetFeature&
  typeNames=namespace:featuretype
```